# ccosl undeclared when trying to use cos(double) from tgmath.h on arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, gcc, newlib, tgmath

Consider the following test code:

```
#include <tgmath.h>

void test()
{
    double x=cos(4.5);
}
```

Compiling it as with

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc test.c -c
```

on Ubuntu 18.04 (gcc 6.3.1, newlib 2.4.0) works fine, but on Ubuntu 20.04 (gcc 9.2.1, newlib 3.3.0) I get the following errors:

```
In file included from test.c:1:
test.c: In function 'test':
test.c:5:14: error: 'ccosl' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'ccosh'?
    5 |     double x=cos(4.5);
      |              ^~~
test.c:5:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
test.c:5:14: error: argument 6 of '__builtin_tgmath' is not a function pointer
```

Apparently, the definition of `cos` has somehow changed, so that it now mentions `ccosl` which is not declared anywhere.

If I change from `tgmath.h` to `math.h`, the error no longer appears. This is of course just a workaround, not a fix, since this way I lose the type genericity for `float` vs `double`.

My question is: how do I make it work properly? Do I have to add some compilation option, or is it just a bug in the toolchain?

Comment: The [`<tgmath.h>` header file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/tgmath) redefines many common [`<math.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math) functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, that's the point of using it

Comment: [C11 7.25p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.25) "The header `<tgmath.h>` includes the headers `<math.h>` and `<complex.h>` and defines several type-generic macros."

Comment: @pmg so that means... what?

Comment: Just a link to the Standard, no other meaning.

Comment: From your question: "Apparently, the definition of `cos` has somehow changed, so that it now mentions `ccosl`" From that it seems you were confused as to why `cos` is redefined as `ccosl`, but that's the whole point of using the `<tgmath.h>` header file (as you mentioned), that it redefines common math functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well, I realize that it should have mentioned `ccosl` all the time (ideally), but it might not have done it in the older version due to possibly unimplemented `long double` versions of functions or whatever.

Comment: Does it work if you declare `long double complex ccosl(long double complex);` in your "test.c" and can you then link it with `-lm`?

Comment: @IanAbbott yes, it compiles and links. The resulting ELF doesn't contain `ccosl` symbol, of course, since this function doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the difference between the versions of the toolchains is in the GCC implementation of `tgmath` `cos` macro in different versions. Namely, compiling with `-E` option for `gcc` yields the following (cleaned up) expansion of `double x=cos(4.5)` in 6.3.1:

```
double x=__builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_classify_type(4.5) == 9,
                               __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(__real__(4.5)), long double),
                                                     ccosl(4.5),
                                                     __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(__real__(4.5)), double) || __builtin_classify_type(__real__(4.5)) == 1,
                                                                           ccos(4.5),
                                                                           ccosf(4.5))
                                                    ),
                               __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(4.5), long double),
                                                     cosl(4.5),
                                                     __builtin_choose_expr(__builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(4.5), double) || __builtin_classify_type(4.5) == 1,
                                                                           cos(4.5),
                                                                           cosf(4.5))
                                                    )
                              );
```

while in GCC 9.3.0 the expansion is as a simple function call:

```
double x=__builtin_tgmath (cosf, cos, cosl, ccosf, ccos, ccosl, 4.5);
```

The main difference between the two is that `__builtin_choose_expr` doesn't evaluate the expression that is not chosen (as said in [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)), while `__builtin_tgmath` is a function, which needs all the arguments to be valid.
And it looks like newlib has never had `ccosl` in its `complex.h`, so it appears incompatible with the newer version of GCC.

Comment: The same sort of failure occurs on Debian "testing" with arm-none-eabi-gcc 8.3.1 and newlib 3.3.0. I wonder if it is including the wrong "tgmath.h" because there is one in "/usr/include/newlib/" and one in "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/include/t" and they are quite different, but "complex.h" and "math.h" only appear in "/usr/include/newlib/".

Comment: Re: my above comment:- Experimentally renaming "/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/include/tgmath.h" to something else resulted in a different error during compilation: "error: first argument to '__builtin_choose_expr' not a constant".

Comment: All the newlib "libm.a" files for the different ARM flavours do seem to have a `ccosl` function, so the problem seems to be the header files. "/usr/include/newlib/complex.h" conditionally declares the `long double complex` functions only if `__CYGWIN__` is defined.